# Prolog recursion doing infinite loop

Tags: recursion, prolog, infinite

Here's the code

```
flight(roc,syr,25).
flight(roc,jfk,55).
flight(jfk,bos,65).
flight(bos,syr,40). 
flight(jfk,syr,50). 
flight(bos,roc,50).

layover(roc,25). 
layover(jfk,55).
layover(syr,30).  
layover(bos,40).

route(X,Y,R,D) :-
   flight(X,Y,L),
   D is L,
   R = [X,Y].
route(X,Y,R,D) :-
   flight(X,Z,L),
   route(Z,Y,P,M), 
   R = [X|P],
   layover(Z,T),
   D is M+L+T,
   \+ member(X,P).
```

Here's what's happening. The second clause

```
route(X,Y,R,D) :-
   flight(X,Z,L),
   route(Z,Y,P,M), 
   R = [X|P], 
   layover(Z,T),
   D is M+L+T,
   \+ member(X,P).
```

goes into an infinite loop. It displays the answers I want, then keeps finding more answers (as you can just keep looping around stops basically) and does an infinite loop until it stops. The program is supposed to find every possible flight route that doesn't loop around stops. I know why this happens, but have no idea how to change my code to fix it. Please help.

Here's one solution

```
?- route(roc, syr, Routing, Duration).
Routing = [roc, syr],
Duration = 25 ;
Routing = [roc, jfk, syr],
Duration = 160 ;
Routing = [roc, jfk, bos, syr],
Duration = 255 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

One caveat to my answer - I am making a few assumptions about your variables.  I assume X is the starting point, Y is the destination, R is the list of locations along path from X to Y (inclusive) and D is the distance traveled?  Or perhaps wait time.  Shouldn't matter.

It looks like a problem with your base case.  Your base case is checking for the existence of a `flight(X,Y,L)` that satisfies the route.  What you need to be checking is whether the list of locations from X to Y (R, if I am not mistaken) already covers from X to Y.  That is, if the last element of list R = Y and the first element of R = X, then you are done.

A last function you could use would be:

```
last([X],X).
last([H|T],R):- last(T,R).
```

Then you can have a base case:

```
route(X,Y,R,D):- last(R,L), L == Y, [H|T] = R, H == X.
```

Or something like that, anyway.  It has been awhile since I have used prolog...

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Guess I didnt explain all the variables. R is the route, D is the distance(gotta count in layover). R and D are the answers, so I don't put them in when i call the rule. Not sure if what you suggested is correct. In the route case you gave, where does H and T come from, and D is never defined.

Comment: ?- route(roc, syr, Routing, Duration).
Routing = [roc, syr],
Duration = 25 ;
Routing = [roc, jfk, syr],
Duration = 160 ;
Routing = [roc, jfk, bos, syr],
Duration = 255 ;
false.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem should be solved moving `\+member(X,P)` *before* the recursive call. That's because Prolog implements logic by means of a *depth first* search of clauses, i.e. top down and left to right selection and match.

Of course moving the test requires a change in `P` computation. Now is built after the visit. A simple way to do is using an accumulator, initialized to [] in first call, and unified to full path on destination. I.e.

```
route(X,Y,Acc, [X,Y|Acc], D) :- flight(X,Y,L), D is L.
...

?- route(roc, syr, [], Routing, Duration).
```